# Ruby on rails how to add .count for attachment record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

I am getting this error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cases.invoice_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cases" WHERE ("cases"."invoice_id" IS ...
                                            ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cases" WHERE ("cases"."invoice_id" IS NOT NULL)
```

I am trying to count all the invoices that I have by doing this code

```
All the Invoice (<%= Case.where.not(invoice: nil).count %>)</h3>
```

How can I make it work?

```
class AddAttachmentInvoiceToCases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :cases do |t|
      t.attachment :invoice
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :cases, :invoice
  end
end


<%= link_to "Your invoice link", item.invoice.url, target: "_blank" %> <% if item.created_at.present? %>
```

Comment: What do you expect to be returned? The number of invoices for a specific case? The number of cases without any invoice? How is the association between cases and attachments defined in the model, as `has_one_attached :invoice` or `has_many_attached :invoices`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are using paperclip. Rails will add these columns to the cases table when you specify `t.attachment :invoice` in your migration file:

1. invoice_file_name
2. invoice_file_size
3. invoice_content_type
4. invoice_updated_at

So, use one of these columns (preferably `invoice_file_name`) to check if the attachment exists.

```
Case.where.not(invoice_file_name: nil).count
```